# TreeTableView disable any cell in parent row

Tags: javafx-8, treetableview, treetablecelleditor

How can I disable any cell editable in parent row in treetableview? Please look the pictures and check the sample code. Shortly I want to disable row editable if row is expandable (root row or sub root row)

this picture is correct
[image]

but this is not correct 
[image]

**Example code **

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TreeTableExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        HBox root = new HBox(createTable());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Using a TreeTableView");
        stage.show();
    }

    public TreeTableView createTable() {

        TreeTableView<Person> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>();
        treeTable.setEditable(true);

        Callback<TreeTableColumn<Person, String>, 
            TreeTableCell<Person, String>> cellFactory
                = (TreeTableColumn<Person, String> p) -> new EditingCell();

        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> firstName = new TreeTableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        firstName.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        firstName.setOnEditCommit((TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String> event) -> {
            if(event.getNewValue()!=null)
                event.getRowValue().getValue().setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
        });

        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> lastName = new TreeTableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        lastName.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        lastName.setOnEditCommit((TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String> event) -> {
            if(event.getNewValue()!=null)
                event.getRowValue().getValue().setLastName(event.getNewValue());
        });

        treeTable.getColumns().addAll(firstName, lastName);
        TreeItem<Person> root = new TreeItem<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person()));
        }
        treeTable.setRoot(root);
        return treeTable;
    }

    public class Person {

        private SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        public Person(){
            firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
            lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
        };

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

    }

    class EditingCell extends TreeTableCell<Person, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText((String) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else if (isEditing()) {
                if(!getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(getIndex()).isLeaf())
                    setEditable(false);
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                    (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                            Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) -> {
                        if (!arg2) {
                            commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        }
                    });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem();
        }
    }
}
```

just run it and double click on the root item

[make-individual-cell-editable-in-javafx-tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414825/make-individual-cell-editable-in-javafx-tableview)  I checked the solution works for tableview but for treetaleview does not work.

Comment: In your cell implementation, you can call `setEditable(true)` or `setEditable(false)` in the `updateItem(...)` method, depending on the item being displayed.

Comment: @James_D thanks for you comment but this does not solve my problem. because as you can see on the picture "Bathing area" is **TreeItem**. if I double click on S.No just view expanded or collapsed. But when I double click on the Item Name column cell is entering editing mode. I want enable cell editing mode only if row is leaf

Comment: The idea is you check in the `updateItem` method whether the tree item is a leaf or not, and set the editable flag accordingly.

Comment: I did but did not work

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with the way you tried to do it.

Comment: `@Override
            public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else{
                    if(!getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(getIndex()).isLeaf())
                        setEditable(false);
                  .....
                } 
            }`   is correct or wrong?

Comment: Impossible to tell from that. I recommend you create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: ok I will add some example as soon as possible

Comment: unrelated: you don't need custom edit handlers if you exposed the properties on Person (the tutorial example is highly suboptimal!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `TreeTableCell` does not properly check its `editable` property before deciding whether or not to call `startEdit()`. I think that's a bug. You can work around it by checking that yourself in your `startEdit()` method:

```
@Override
public void startEdit() {
    if (isEditable() && !isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();
        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }
}
```

and now in your `updateItem()` method, you can check the current tree item from the row, and update `editable` as required:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    TreeItem<Person> treeItem = getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem();
    setEditable(treeItem != null &&  treeItem.isLeaf());

    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else if (isEditing()) {
        if(!getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(getIndex()).isLeaf())
            setEditable(false);
        if (textField != null) {
            textField.setText(getString());
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
    } else {
        setText(getString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. now is working. As you mentioned problem is I did not check that the cell is editable or not in startEdit() method

Comment: unrelated: no need to expand the scope of updateItem (to public) - it's strictly for use in the class itself (polite cough :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I disagree with the reasoning in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567847/203657): there is nothing wrong with core TreeTableCell (it *does* check for its editability before actually starting an edit) - instead the logic in the custom cell implementation is broken. Particularly, the part of updateItem that sets the editable property:

```
} else if (isEditing()) {
    if(!getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(getIndex()).isLeaf())
        setEditable(false);
```

Besides being incomplete in not resetting the editable back to true anywhere (remember: cells are re-used), we allow super to *first* start editing and only *after* it started, it's disabled.

This logic error is fixed (in the other answer, copied here for convenience) by unconditionally setting the editability in updateItem:

```
super.updateItem(item, empty);

TreeItem<Person> treeItem = getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem();
setEditable(treeItem != null &&  treeItem.isLeaf());
```

The other usage error (as already noted) was not fully checking cell state before actually configuring the editor. The suggested fix - check cell's editable - isn't quite complete because table/column editability might be disabled as well. To take that into account, I would tend to let super do its job and only configure the editor if editability actually changed, like

```
super.startEdit();
// super changed state into editing 
if (isEditing()) {
   // create and install the textField
}
```