# Seting TableCell Disable programmatically wierd behaivior

Tags: javafx-8

I have a table with quantity and price columns that are editable and not disabled. The table is populated with `ObservableList<Collection>` . `Collection` object has a `boolean` attribute `paid`. What i am tring to achieve is whenever `paid` is true, make both price and quantity tablecells disabled and not editable.

This is what i have done so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.FloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.converter.FloatStringConverter;

public class CollectionTable extends Application{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TableView<Collection> tv = new TableView();
    tv.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Collection, Number> colQty = createQuantityColumn();
    colQty.setCellFactory(
        new Callback<TableColumn<Collection, Number>, TableCell<Collection, Number>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Collection, Number> call(TableColumn<Collection, Number> paramTableColumn) {
                return new TextFieldTableCell<Collection, Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Number s, boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(s, b);

                        TableRow row = getTableRow();
                        if (row != null) {
                            Collection item = (Collection) row.getItem();
                            //Test for disable condition
                            if (item != null && item.isPaid()) {
                                setDisable(true);
                                setEditable(false);
                                this.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: grey;-fx-border-color: red");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
    });
    TableColumn<Collection, Number> colPrice = createPriceColumn();

    colPrice.setCellFactory(
        new Callback<TableColumn<Collection, Number>, TableCell<Collection, Number>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Collection, Number> call(TableColumn<Collection, Number> paramTableColumn) {
                return new TextFieldTableCell<Collection, Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Number s, boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(s, b);

                        TableRow row = getTableRow();
                        if (row != null) {
                            Collection item = (Collection) row.getItem();
                            //Test for disable condition
                            if (item != null && !item.isPaid()) {
                                setDisable(true);
                                setEditable(false);
                                this.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: grey;-fx-border-color: red");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
    });
    TableColumn<Collection, Number> colAmount = createAmountColumn();
    TableColumn<Collection, String> colMno = createMNOColumn();

    tv.getColumns().addAll(colMno, colQty, colPrice, colAmount);
    tv.getItems().addAll(getCollection());
    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(tv), 600, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private TableColumn createQuantityColumn() {
    TableColumn<Collection, Float> colQty = new TableColumn("Quantity");
    colQty.setMinWidth(25);
    colQty.setId("colQty");
    colQty.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Collection, Float>forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
    colQty.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty().asObject());
    colQty.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Collection, Float>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Collection, Float> t) {


        }
    });
    return colQty;
}

private TableColumn createPriceColumn() {
    TableColumn<Collection, Float> colPrice = new TableColumn("Price");
    colPrice.setMinWidth(25);
    colPrice.setId("colPrice");
    colPrice.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Collection, Float>forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
    colPrice.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty().asObject());
    colPrice.setOnEditStart(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Collection, Float>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Collection, Float> t) {
            Collection c = ((Collection) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()));
            c.setPrice(Math.abs(c.getPrice()));
        }
    });
    colPrice.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Collection, Float>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Collection, Float> t) {
            Collection c = ((Collection) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()));
            c.setPrice(Math.abs((float)t.getNewValue()));
            //int i = collectionHandler.updateCollection(c);
        }
    });
    return colPrice;
}

private TableColumn createAmountColumn() {
    TableColumn<Collection, Float> colAmount = new TableColumn("Amount");
    colAmount.setMinWidth(25);
    colAmount.setId("colAmount");
    colAmount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().amountProperty().asObject());
    return colAmount;
}

private TableColumn createMNOColumn() {
    TableColumn colMNO = new TableColumn("M/NO");
    colMNO.setMinWidth(25);
    colMNO.setId("colMNO");
    colMNO.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("mno"));
    return colMNO;
}

private List<Collection> getCollection(){
    List<Collection> collections = new ArrayList<>();
    collections.add(new Collection(1, 10, "1", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(2, 10, "12", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(3, 10, "123", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(4, 10, "312", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(5, 10, "311", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(6, 10, "322", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(7, 10, "333", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(8, 10, "321", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(9, 10, "456", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(10, 10, "551", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(11, 10, "515", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(12, 10, "134", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(13, 10, "789", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(14, 10, "879", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(15, 10, "987", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(16, 10, "856", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(17, 10, "956", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(18, 10, "589", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(19, 10, "852", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(20, 10, "456", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(21, 10, "623", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(22, 10, "147", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(23, 10, "125", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(24, 10, "258", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(25, 10, "325", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(26, 10, "753", true));
    collections.add(new Collection(27, 10, "357", false));
    collections.add(new Collection(28, 10, "159", false));
    return collections;
}

public class Collection{
    private final FloatProperty quantity  = new SimpleFloatProperty();
    private final FloatProperty price  = new SimpleFloatProperty();
    private final FloatProperty amount  = new SimpleFloatProperty();
    private final BooleanProperty paid = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private String mno;

    public Collection(){
        this(0f, 0f, null, false);
    }

    public Collection(float quantity, float price, String mno, boolean paid) {
        setQuantity(quantity);
        setPrice(price);
        setMno(mno);
        setPaid(paid);
        this.amount.bind(this.quantity.multiply(this.price));
    }

    public String getMno() {
        return mno;
    }

    public void setMno(String mno) {
        this.mno = mno;
    }

    public float getQuantity() {
        return quantityProperty().get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(float quantity) {
        quantityProperty().set(quantity);
    }

    public FloatProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity ;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return priceProperty().get();
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        priceProperty().set(price);
    }

    public FloatProperty priceProperty() {
        return price ;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amountProperty().get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyFloatProperty amountProperty() {
        return amount ;
    }

    public BooleanProperty paidProperty() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void setPaid(boolean approved) {
        this.paid.set(approved);
    }

    public boolean isPaid() {
        return paid.get();
    }
}
}
```

The problem with my code is that as i scroll down the table and up again, cells which were previously enabled and editable change to disabled and not editable.

Before scroll [image] After scroll: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't reset the state when a cell is reused from one which is paid to one which is not paid. This will happen, among other times, when you scroll. If a cell was previously used in a row that represented a "paid" item (so it is disabled, not editable, and has a red border), and is reused for an "unpaid" item, your `updateItem()` method will not change the editable or disabled state (or the style). So you should have something like:

```
if (item != null && item.isPaid()) {
    setDisable(true);
    setEditable(false);
    this.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: grey;-fx-border-color: red");
} else {
    setDisable(false);
    setEditable(true);
    setStyle("");
}
```

The second problem is that you have no control over the order in which the cell's state is updated. It seems that sometimes the row property is updated *after* the `updateItem()` method is called, so you end up with inconsistent state. You can safely use the cell's index to get the correct item from the table's data.

Also note that since both cell factories are identical, there is no need to replicate the code. This works for me:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TableView<Collection> tv = new TableView();
    tv.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Collection, Number> colQty = createQuantityColumn();
    Callback<TableColumn<Collection, Number>, TableCell<Collection, Number>> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<Collection, Number>, TableCell<Collection, Number>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Collection, Number> call(TableColumn<Collection, Number> paramTableColumn) {
            return new TextFieldTableCell<Collection, Number>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number s, boolean b) {
                    super.updateItem(s, b);

                    if (! isEmpty()) {
                        Collection item = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        // Test for disable condition
                        if (item != null && item.isPaid()) {
                            setDisable(true);
                            setEditable(false);
                            this.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: grey;-fx-border-color: red");
                        } else {
                            setDisable(false);
                            setEditable(true);
                            setStyle("");
                        }
                    } 
                }
            };
        }
    };
    colQty.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    TableColumn<Collection, Number> colPrice = createPriceColumn();


    colPrice.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    TableColumn<Collection, Number> colAmount = createAmountColumn();
    TableColumn<Collection, String> colMno = createMNOColumn();

    tv.getColumns().addAll(colMno, colQty, colPrice, colAmount);
    tv.getItems().addAll(getCollection());
    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(tv), 600, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: You are the best!Works like a charm

Comment: I tried using your solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414825/make-individual-cell-editable-in-javafx-tableview) on this very problem, am getting same weird behaviour. I have already posted a question   [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125162/tablecell-wrongly-toggle-tablecell-editability). Please check it out.